# Push to array depends on options

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, logic

That's option object:

```js
const options = {
  groupZ: true, groupY: true,
  category1: true, category2: true, category3: true,
  Zcategory1: true, Zcategory2: true, Zcategory3: true, Zcategory4: true,
  Ycategory1: true, Ycategory2: true, Ycategory3: true, Ycategory5: true
}
```

That's how I build response object:

```js
{
  ...groupZ && {
    ...Zcategory1 && { /* stuff */ }
    ...Zcategory2 && { /* stuff */ }
    ...Zcategory3 && { /* stuff */ }
    ...Zcategory4 && { /* stuff */ }
  },
  ...groupY && {
    ...Ycategory1 && { /* stuff */ }
    ...Ycategory2 && { /* stuff */ }
    ...Ycategory3 && { /* stuff */ }
    ...Ycategory5 && { /* stuff */ }
  }
}
```

So I need to fill array depends on options I got:

```js
const array = [];
// if all options is true
// pushing every example functions I got
array.push(
  ExampleFunction1('param1'); // will return array of strings
  ExampleFunction1('param2');
  ExampleFunction2();
  ExampleFunction3();
  ExampleFunction4('param1');
  ExampleFunction4('param2');
  ExampleFunction5('param1');
  ExampleFunction5('param2');
);

// if Ycategory2 is false, push everything but ExampleFunction5('param2');
array.push(
  ExampleFunction1('param1'); // will return array of strings
  ExampleFunction1('param2');
  ExampleFunction2();
  ExampleFunction3();
  ExampleFunction4('param1');
  ExampleFunction4('param2');
  ExampleFunction5('param1');
  // ExampleFunction5('param2'); remove that
);

// if groupY if false:
array.push(
  ExampleFunction1('param1'); // will return array of strings
  // ExampleFunction1('param2');
  ExampleFunction2(); // keep that
  // ExampleFunction3();
  ExampleFunction4('param1');
  // ExampleFunction4('param2');
  ExampleFunction5('param1');
  // ExampleFunction5('param2'); remove that
);
```

Logic:

All options `true` by default

if `Zcategory2` is `false`, for example, ignore `category2` option

if any options besides `groupZ` and `groupY` is false ignore `groupZ` and `groupY`

if `groupZ` is false ignore everything with `Z` (Zcategory1, Zcategory2, etc), same with `groupY`

I hope that enough information.

Also I don't want 100 lines of code with `if` `else` because that makes code unreadable and that what I have right now.

example / what I have right now:

```js
if (options.groupZ === false && options.category1 === false && options.Zcategory1 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction5('param1'))
if (options.groupZ === false && options.category2 === false && options.Zcategory2 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction2()
if (options.groupZ === false && options.category3 === false && options.Zcategory3 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction1('param1'))
if (options.groupZ === false && options.Zcategory3 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction4('param1'))

if (options.groupY === false && options.category1 === false && options.Zcategory1 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction5('param2'))
if (options.groupY === false && options.category2 === false && options.Zcategory2 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction3()
if (options.groupY === false && options.category3 === false && options.Zcategory3 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction1('param2'))
if (options.groupY === false && options.Zcategory3 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction4('param2'))

if (options.category1 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction5('param1'), ExampleFunction5('param2'))
if (options.category2 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction2(), ExampleFunction3())
if (options.category3 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction1('param1'), ExampleFunction1('param'))

if (options.groupZ) array.push(
  ExampleFunction1('param1'),
  ExampleFunction2(),
  ExampleFunction4('param1'),
  ExampleFunction5('param1')
)

if (options.groupY) array.push(
  ExampleFunction1('param2'),
  ExampleFunction3(),
  ExampleFunction4('param2'),
  ExampleFunction5('param2')
)
```

Comment: do you have a smaller example with som running code?

Comment: I think you should flatten things before continuing. Maybe use some function to make this more understandable

Comment: @NinaScholz `if (opts.pvp === false && opts.category1 === false opts.Zcategory1 === true) array.push(ExampleFunction5('param1'))`

Comment: do you have only boolean values? then you could take the value directly or with logical NOT `!` for a `false` check.

Comment: @NinaScholz all options values is boolean

Comment: An example would really be helpfu;

Comment: @shrys added example

Comment: please add some more, what you have, what you want and what you do.

Comment: I assume you want to do all of the if conditions in one go. If that is the case Lose the destructuring, replace curly braces (stuff) with IIFE and and do this for groupZ and groupY in two separate lines

Comment: @NinaScholz I added a bit more